# Predict results in ‘’TensorFlow serving‘’ and ‘’local model reload‘’ is different

Tags: python, tensorflow, bert-language-model

I'm predicting using the same model. The result is different, but it shouldn't be since it's same model (first model saved into file, then second model is created from loading the file).
I test to reshape the tensorflow-serving inputs to like `"{"input_word_ids": [encodes['input_ids']]..."`, but it did not work.

Input into tensorflow serving:

```
 inputs= {"instances": [{"input_word_ids": encodes['input_ids'], "input_mask": encodes['input_ids'], "input_type_ids": encodes['input_ids']}]}
 headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
 json_response = requests.post('http://localhost:8501/v1/models/bert_model:predict',
                                  data=json.dumps(inputs), headers=headers)
result:[[-0.998641431, -0.812168241, 2.3345871, 1.79382575, -0.00233620172, -3.28864908, -0.531166852, -0.705040932, 2.24861217, 1.16766787, 0.893842638, 0.882387042, -0.419321597, -1.92870927, 0.00293750782, 0.571823, -1.0008961, 0.25918898, -2.7151773, 1.1212393, 1.05252075, 0.621426523, 0.428827167]]
```

Input into local model:

```
encodes = tokenizer.encode_plus(text,
                                     add_special_tokens=True,  # add [CLS], [SEP]
                                     max_length=max_length,  # max length of the text that can go to 
                                     pad_to_max_length=True,  # add [PAD] tokens
                                     return_attention_mask=True,  # add attention mask )

inputs = {
    'input_word_ids': tf.convert_to_tensor([encodes['input_ids']]),
    'input_mask': tf.convert_to_tensor([encodes['token_type_ids']]),
    'input_type_ids': tf.convert_to_tensor([encodes['token_type_ids']])}
load_model = tf.saved_model.load(export_dir)
result = load_model(inputs, training=False)
result:tf.Tensor(
    [[-1.8024038  -1.3173668  -0.08120027 -2.0854492  -0.50478387  2.9193602
       0.2091662  -0.01863982 -1.0049771  -1.7226878  -1.5322843  -0.97847456
      -1.1123526   7.5573688  -0.5297349  -2.2933776  -1.3478909  -3.367974
      -0.08475648 -1.229377    3.276103   -0.26380143  1.2428844 ]], shape=(1, 23), dtype=float32)
```

What is wrong here?